# get content from flash site

Tags: php, curl

I have been using php-curl to get content from html based sites and http analyzer to monitor traffic, is it possible to scrape certain text from flash site, (that text is being updated after X seconds on site)? I tried to monitor with http analyzer and fiddler but it does not display updating text process.

Comment: you have permission from the site owner?

Answer (score 0):

This would probably only be possible with screen readers or something... You could download the Flash file, extract it and 'parse' it, but that's about it. It's not possible to rip the content automatically as with HTML.

That's the essence of the problem with Flash sites when it comes to findability on Google.

Comment: Google bot can actually "read" *some* Flash contents, but of course not always working as desired :P Flash is not SEO-friendly

Comment: As far as I know, that's only when the developer poses an alternative version to bots. I'm not 100% sure though.

Comment: You can refer to [this](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=72746#1)